# In a outlook web add-in suddenly stops giving email address for sender/from object

Tags: office-js, outlook-web-addins

In my outlook web addin it suddenly stops giving email address of from & sender object, My code looks like:

```
isSentItem() {
    return Office.context.mailbox.userProfile.emailAddress === Office.context.mailbox.item.sender.emailAddress;
}
```

I checked in console display name is coming correct but email address not populating:

[image]

I am using cdn hosted officejs api:

```
<script src="https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1/hosted/office.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Current version of officejs api shows

```
/* Office JavaScript API library */
/* Version: 16.0.7805.1000 */
```

Outlook client version - `Outlook 2016 MSO (16.0.4498.1000) 32-bit`

**Note: I am running above piece of code for message item in SentItem folder. For message in Inbox are working fine.**

Answer (score 3):

If you are running this in your sent items folder as an example, this is a known issue and being addressed! This should however not happen for messages that are delivered to you (as in on the messages in the inbox).

Comment: Yes it is happening in sent item messages are in inbox are doing fine. Do you have any reference link where I can followup this issue or do you have any idea about the timeline of this issue.

Comment: I'm following up with AnOberoi to get details on this. We'll update this thread once we have a resolution.

Comment: This issue will be fixed in Office 2016 C2R first soon. (likely in a 16.0.8XXX) build. After the fix comes to C2R it will be in MSI (2016 and 2013) a few months later.