# Item.from.emailAddress is empty string for sent items in Outlook 2013/2016

Tags: office-js, office-addins, outlook-web-addins

I have an add-in that displays a profile of the sender, which is working great in OWA and in most cases installed Outlook. However, I just discovered that when viewing items in the sent folder, the item.from.emailAddress field is empty. The displayName appears correct, but the email is just an empty string. This is only on the installed Outlook 2013 and 2016 apps on Windows.

Another difference between OWA and Outlook that I've seen is the recipientType field for the from property. This is documented as not being defined for the from field, though I actually do see that properly set in OWA.

Comment: the item.from and item.sender properties are not present for items in the sent items folder. This is a known issue for Outlook 2013 and some versions of Outlook 2016, could you confirm your build number for 2016. This has been fixed in current/newer versions of Outlook 2016.

Comment: possible duplication: [In a outlook web add-in suddenly stops giving email address for sender/from object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42272013/in-a-outlook-web-add-in-suddenly-stops-giving-email-address-for-sender-from-obje)